# ionic3 error cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file on run to android device

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an ionic 3 project. I had to update some plugins and some ionic modules (and also corodva). After updates I can add android platform on my project but I cant run on my android device any more!!! 
this is the error:

```
> cordova run android --device
cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=ENOENT):D:\roxangit\roxanne-beta\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml

Parsing D:\roxangit\roxanne-beta\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml failed
(node:9760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\roxangit\roxanne-beta\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml'
```

It seems that "cordova platform add android" command doesn't create are required files and folders!

Here is my ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2 (C:\Users\Xarrin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : none
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic 5.2.4, cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.1.4, (and 15 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\Xarrin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk)
   NodeJS            : v6.9.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 3.10.8
   OS                : Windows 10
```

And this is out put of add android platform:

```
> cordova platform add android --save
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~7.0.0
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
        Path: platforms\android
        Package: com.ionicframework.roxannebeta
        Name: roxanne_beta
        Activity: MainActivity
        Android target: android-26
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Android project created with cordova-android@7.0.0
Android Studio project detected
Android Studio project detected
Installing "cordova-open-native-settings" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-console" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-device" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-file" for android

The Android Persistent storage location now defaults to "Internal". Please check this plugin's README to see if your application needs any changes in its config.xml.

If this is a new application no changes are required.

If this is an update to an existing application that did not specify an "AndroidPersistentFileLocation" you may need to add:

      "<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />"

to config.xml in order for the application to find previously stored files.

Installing "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" for android
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-file@6.0.1" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-file" already installed on android.
Installing "cordova-plugin-http" for android
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-file@6.0.1" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-file" already installed on android.
Installing "cordova-plugin-ionic" for android
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-splashscreen@5.0.2" already fetched, using that version.
Installing "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" for android
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@2.1.4" already fetched, using that version.
Installing "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-file@6.0.1" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-file" already installed on android.
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-file-transfer@1.7.1" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" already installed on android.
Installing "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" for android
Plugin "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" already installed on android. Making it top-level.
Installing "cordova-plugin-network-information" for android
Plugin "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" already installed on android. Making it top-level.
Installing "cordova-plugin-statusbar" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-vibration" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android

               This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.

Installing "cordova-plugin-zeroconf" for android
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support@1.7.2" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support" already installed on android.
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Installing "cordova-sqlite-storage" for android
installing external dependencies via npm
npm install of external dependencies ok
Installing "ionic-plugin-keyboard" for android
Failed to install 'ionic-plugin-keyboard': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\roxangit\roxanne-beta\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:508:33)
    at Object.parseElementtreeSync (D:\roxangit\roxanne-beta\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\util\xml-helpers.js:180:27)
    at new AndroidManifest (D:\roxangit\roxanne-beta\platforms\android\cordova\lib\AndroidManifest.js:29:20)
    at AndroidProject.getPackageName (D:\roxangit\roxanne-beta\platforms\android\cordova\lib\AndroidProject.js:99:12)
    at Api.addPlugin (D:\roxangit\roxanne-beta\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js:223:57)
    at handleInstall (C:\Users\Xarrin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\install.js:594:10)
    at C:\Users\Xarrin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\install.js:357:28
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Xarrin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
(node:9752) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\roxangit\roxanne-beta\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml'
> ionic cordova resources android --force
√ Collecting resource configuration and source images - done!
√ Filtering out image resources that do not need regeneration - done!
√ Uploading source images to prepare for transformations: 2 / 2 complete - done!
√ Generating platform resources: 18 / 18 complete - done!
√ Modifying config.xml to add new image resources - done!
```

Please help me! I can't work on my project if I couldn't run or build the project.

Comment: post cordova platform add android console logs

Comment: Platform directory formation for 7.0.0 totally differs from 6.3.0, that's why the copy file sync throwing error when looking for Android manifest XML file, why can't you add cordova platform add android@6.3.0 ?

Comment: I tried to add 6.3.0  but i get an error with ionic-plugin-keyboard. I remove the ionic-plugin-keyboard form package.json and config.xml but still get this error: Failed to install 'ionic-plugin-keyboard': CordovaError: Uh oh!
"D:\roxangit\roxanne-beta\platforms\android\src\io\ionic\keyboard\IonicKeyboard.java" already exists!

Comment: @Ravikumar Finally I add android@6.4.0 and the run android --device but the problem is that I can't see my local changes in the app!!! It seems that the app runs in android device from cache or somewhere else!!